# How update a SQL table from a modified datatable?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I used the DataSet Designer to create FTWDataSet which holds the AlarmText table from a SQLExpress database.  This far my form contains ONLY Datagridview1.  The code below successfully shows the contents of the AlarmText table plus the one added checkbox column (which I will populate with display-only data, and is not an issue here).

```
    Dim ta As New FTWDataSetTableAdapters.AlarmTextTableAdapter
    Dim dt As New FTWDataSet.AlarmTextDataTable
    ta.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    'create a new Bool column in the datatable
    dt.Columns.Add("NewCol", (New Boolean).GetType)
```

What else do I need to do to use the DataGridView to edit and save values in the AlarmText table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a brief [MSDN walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933.aspx) on this topic.

Some notes:

- You shouldn't need a binding source to persist changes back to the database.
- To make the table adapter accessible to other procedures in your form, make it a form-scoped (a.k.a. member) variable instead of method-scoped, as in your example.
- If you created your `Dataset` using the Dataset Designer, and you're fetching your original data from anything more than a simple table or view, then your adapter won't know how to update anything in the original database. You have to manually configure the `UPDATE` command in this situation. For reference, see the TableAdapter Update Commands section in the above link.

I should also mention that I avoid TableAdapters in ADO.Net like the plague. In theory they're very convenient and powerful. In practice, many of them (especially the one for the Oracle provider) are buggy, and if they don't work exactly right you're totally screwed.

If you're pulling from just one underlying table, the adapter should work fine (so ignore my nihilistic advice for the time being). It may be that adding an additional column in code will breaks the adapter (since there's no corresponding column in the database table).

Comment: Yes, I thought a table adapter and binding source would be involved.  But I don't have a binding source, and the table adapter that was referenced in the code (Load event) I've shown is not accessible from any other procedure.

Comment: I moved the dim ta as New . . . statement to just under the Public Class statement for the form.  I also added a DataSet component called DataSet1, with a reference to the dataset I created in Designer, to the form.  Then I added ta.Update(Me.DataSet1.AlarmText) to the DataGridView Validated event.  It all runs but nothing is getting saved.  The Validated event is definitely firing.  Thanks for your help so far . . .

Comment: Also moved ta.Update(Me.DataSet1.AlarmText) to the grid's CellValueChanged event.  Still not saving.

Comment: In my link above, go to the TableAdapter Update Commands section. If you created your Dataset using the Dataset Designer, and you're fetching your original data from anything more than a simple table or view, then your adapter won't know how to update anything in the original database. You have to manually configure the UPDATE command in this situation.

Comment: First, my data IS just in a simple table in the SQL database.  Second, I'll take your advice about avoiding the table adapters - but I still don't see a solution to being able to use the grid to display and save data from a SQL table, AND display data I've created with my program.

Comment: Well, if you're pulling from just one underlying table, the adapter *should* work fine (so ignore my nihilistic advice for the time being). It may be that adding the additional column in code ("NewCol") breaks the adapter (since there's no corresponding column in the database table).

Comment: So I went back to draging the datatable from the DataSource pane onto the form, then adding extra columns to the dataviewgrid only.  The TableAdapter Update method works fine for the columns that are part of the datatable.  Thanks very much for your advice.